# Router view on Vue 3 doesn't catch event from child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I just checked that the router-view(in Vue 3) doesn't catch event that are sent from child. For example:

```
  <router-view
    @event-test="$emit('new-test-event')"
  />
```

Here my child send `event-test` but the `router-view` never catch It, so the `new-test-event` is never emitted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found this warning :

```
[Vue Router warn]: <router-view> can no longer be used directly inside <transition> or <keep-alive>.
Use slot props instead:

<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

So the answer is to make this:

```
  <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
      <component :is="Component" @event-test="$emit('new-test-event')"/>
  </router-view>
```

Comment: did you encounter any test errors after making this change? I get a test error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Component')`

Comment: I think it's related with the router-view, you have to mock router-view with a Component prop

Comment: Figured it out! Had accidentally left a `@vue/test-utils` config in there. Taking this out solved the issue. `config.renderStubDefaultSlot = true`